# Return Body Text from Fetch API

Tags: promise, fetch

I would like to return the response body text returned by the POST that I send by fetch.

```
var r = '';
var res = fetch(this.commentsUrl, {
  method: 'post',
  body: JSON.stringify(comment),
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
}).then(function (response) {
  return response.text().then(function (text) {
    r = text;
  })
});
```

Neither r or res is returning the body text. They are both returning Promise. How do I only return the body text?

Comment: try calling res. Since javascript makes asynchronous call, you might wanna use await.

Comment: It's giving an error TS2322: Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'string'.

Comment: if the api return json response use response.json()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to get the response body text by using `await`.

```
const response = await fetch(this.commentsUrl, {
  method: 'post',
  body: JSON.stringify(comment),
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
});

const text = await response.text();
```

Comment: This (https://rapidapi.com/guides/fetch-api-async-await) explains it best. In essence, the return of await fetch is an object with several properties. One of them is text() which itself is a promise so we must await it to use it.